# Not sure why my C program is giving the error code "Process exited after 2.55 seconds with return value 3221225477" when dealing with linked lists

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I am building a Student Management System and it has to make use of linked lists.
One of the requirements is that each student has to have a list of courses that they are enrolled in. To handle that I implemented 2 separate linked lists and then joined them where necessary. But when executing the `printList` function, only the last student entered gets output and then the above mentioned error code appears. Additionally, I tried running the code in an online compiler and it worked fine, any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Structures creation
typedef struct course {
    char courseName[40];
    int credits;
    struct course *nextCourse;
} course;

typedef struct student {
    char firstName[50];
    char lastName[50];
    int age;
    char address[100];
    char progName[60];
    course *courseList;
    struct student *next;
} student;

void *checkMalloc(size_t num_bytes);
void addStudent(student **headStd, char *fName, char *lName, int age, char *address, char *progName);
void addCourse(student *currStd, char *cName, int cred);
void printList(student *first);

int main() {
    student *headStd = NULL;
    
    addStudent(&headStd, "John", "Doe", 19, "Lot 123", "Comp Sci");
    addCourse(headStd, "CSE2100", 4);
    addCourse(headStd, "CSE2101", 4);
    
    addStudent(&headStd, "Jane", "Smith", 20, "Lot 3 East Street", "Info Sys");
    addCourse(headStd, "ISY2100", 4);
    addCourse(headStd, "ITE2101", 3);
    
    printList(headStd);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;    
}

void addStudent(student **headStd, char *fName, char *lName, int age, char *address, char *progName) {
    student *newStd = checkMalloc(sizeof(*newStd));

    strcpy(newStd->firstName, fName);
    strcpy(newStd->lastName, lName);
    newStd->age = age;
    strcpy(newStd->address, address);
    strcpy(newStd->progName, progName);

    // This line was missing in the original code posted
    // newStd->courseList = NULL;

    newStd->next = (*headStd);
    (*headStd) = newStd;
}

void addCourse(student *currStd, char *cName, int cred) {
    //Memory allocation
    course *newCourse = checkMalloc(sizeof(*newCourse));

    strcpy(newCourse->courseName, cName);
    newCourse->credits = cred;
    
    newCourse->nextCourse = currStd->courseList;
    currStd->courseList = newCourse;
}

void printList(student *first) {
    while (first != NULL) {
        printf("Name: %s %s\n", first->firstName, first->lastName);
        printf("Age: %d\n", first->age);
        printf("Address: %s\n", first->address);
        printf("Program Enrolled: %s\n", first->progName);
        
        course *currCourse = first->courseList;
        if (currCourse == NULL) {
            printf("\tNo Courses Present\n");
        } else {
            while (currCourse != NULL) {
                printf("\tCourse Name: %s\n", currCourse->courseName);
                printf("\tCourse Credits: %d\n", currCourse->credits);
                currCourse = currCourse->nextCourse; 
            }
        }
        first = first->next;
    }
}

void *checkMalloc(size_t num_bytes) {
    void *memory = malloc(num_bytes);
    if (memory == NULL) {
        printf("Error, couldn't allocate memory.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return memory;
}
```

Comment: `addStudent` does not initialise `courseList`. Add `newStd->courseList = NULL`.

Comment: @kaylum I just tried to initialize `courseList` and got the same issue.

Comment: Where did you initialise `courseList`?

Comment: That may just be one of the problems. Best tip you'll get: Learn to debug the code effectively yourself instead of having to rely on others to do it for you. Run the program in a debugger and step thru it line by line. The `courseList` issue for example should easily be found if you do basic debugging. More tips here: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Cheatah I tried initializing it within the `addStudent` function after this line of code: `strcpy(newStd->progName, progName);`.

Comment: @RahulGoolghar Well I don't see it, so I'll have to just assume you did that wrong then.

Comment: When using a debugging tool, I'm getting a segmentation fault.
And that's occurring whenever I try to output the list of courses.

Comment: The program has memory leaks, otherwise I don't see a problem, and neither do valgrind and the address/UB sanitizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you posted, the member `newStd->courseList` is not initialized by the function `addStudent`. Since the memory is allocated with `malloc`, its contents is indeterminate, meaning the pointer `courseList` might be an invalid pointer.

You then insert a list of courses before this invalid pointer...
The same happens for the second student... invalid pointers there have not been dereferenced, but are waiting to bite like poison snakes.

When you print the student details and the list of courses, after the last course the line `currCourse = currCourse->nextCourse;` reads the invalid pointer into `currCourse` and the next iteration will crash when dereferencing this pointer.

This explains the observed behavior, but this undefined behavior is not guaranteed to be observable as `malloc` may also return memory that happens to be filled with all bits zero, so the initial value of `newStd->courseList` could be a null pointer.

The fix is simple: add `newStd->courseList = NULL;` in `addStudent()`.